# Multiple JSON parameters with MVC3 view model and knockout model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I am having some trouble with sending data back to my MVC3 controller through JSON.

My ultimate goal is for my controller to recieve both the data from knockout and the current model from the view.

I have no trouble getting back the observable array, and no trouble getting back the original model used to populate the view. But I cannot get the updates made to the model in the browser.

Normally a submit automagically sends back the view model, and I think i just need to call that mechanism.

my code currently gets me the knockout array correctly, but the model is "old" it is the data that was used to populate the view from the server.

I am really looking for how to initiate the mechanism on the form that would allow me to send the data back through JSON (or another better way)

Edit: the data line has been changed. and i now get the model back, but the array of items is sized correctly but with empty items. It looks like the knockout mapping didn't quite work.

Controller sig:

```
public ActionResult Save(
                           IEnumerable<ItemModel> eventlist,
                           ViewHeaderModel model)


     var vm = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: '/controller/schedule/save,
            data: $('#myForm').serialize()+"&" +$.param({'eventlist': ko.toJS(self.DraftKoModel.ScheduleItems)}),
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            traditional: true,
            success: function (result) {
              alert("HEEEEEEELP! I'm trapped!")
            } 
        });
```

Comment: Can you post the Controller Action you are posting the data to ? I wanted to look at the Model you are expecting on the controller

Comment: Edits above answer you. Hope you can help. I am so close i can taste it!

Answer (score 0):

Just tested added a quick test page to my app.  The code below should work:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/controller/schedule/save',
    data: $("#myForm").serialize() + "&" + $.param({'eventlist' : ko.toJS(self.DraftKoModel.ScheduleItems}),
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "application/JSON",
    success: function (result) {
          alert("HEEEEEEELP! I'm trapped!")
        } 
});
```

[Put this together using this blog post as a reference.](http://www.jblotus.com/2011/07/12/combine-serialized-form-post-data-with-arbitrary-object-in-jquery/)

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: When i do this the Model is null... so something is happening but not what is getting processed right i guess :|

Comment: updated answer.  you might also need to use JSON.stringify() so feel free to swap out my $.param. let me know if that works now.

Comment: I am toying with this now.

I also noticed that my previous code worked if i removed the "Datatype: "application/JSON" but only for the model. So it is like one string is in the right format and the other is not.

Comment: data: $('#myForm').serialize()+"&" +$.param({'eventlist': ko.toJS(self.DraftKoModel.ScheduleItems)}),

Seems to have gotten very very close to what i need. I now get the model with updated data (YAY) and a list from knockout with 99 items, which is correct... but all of the list items are empty... Any idea with that last little bug?

Comment: did you try it like this?  $('#myForm').serialize() + "&" + JSON.stringify(({'eventlist': ko.toJS(self.DraftKoModel.ScheduleItems)})

Comment: I did. After i do that it cracks into the forms serialization and says "Invalid JSON primitive: MyProperty."